# Dynamic Pivot on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table (called transactions) that contains information relating to transactions. Transactions can have multiple comments and an accompanying detail (detail is not compulsory) against them but some transactions won't have any comments against them. For each comment made against a transaction there is a new record created in the table containing the same data for some fields (date, time, amount, type) for all records of the same transaction whilst some fields in the record relate only to that particular comment and detail.

See sample data below:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------------+-----------------+
| Date      | Time    | Amount  | Type | Comment        | Detail          |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------------+-----------------+
| 13/9/2017 | 9:00AM  | $12.10  | Cash |                |                 |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------------+-----------------+
| 13/9/2017 | 9:30AM  | $22.45  | Card |                |                 |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------------+-----------------+
| 13/9/2017 | 9:30AM  | $22.45  | Card | Delivery       | deliver to rear |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------------+-----------------+
| 13/9/2017 | 9:30AM  | $22.45  | Card | ReturnCustomer | yes             |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------------+-----------------+
| 13/9/2017 | 9:45AM  | $-34.00 | Cash | Refund         |                 |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------------+-----------------+
| 13/9/2017 | 10:00AM | $17.67  | Card |                |                 |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------------+-----------------+
| 13/9/2017 | 10:00AM | $17.67  | Card | Deposit        | 10%             |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------------+-----------------+
```

I need to return a single row for each specific transaction and if any comments/detail have been made against a transaction they are to be pivoted into its own column (1 for comment and 1 for detail). For transactions where more than 1 comment was made, they need to be their own new column and detail.

So the data above needs to be returned like this:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+-----------------+----------------+---------+
| Date      | Time    | Amount  | Type | Comment1 | Detail1         | Comment2       | Detail2 |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+-----------------+----------------+---------+
| 13/9/2017 | 9:00AM  | $12.10  | Cash |          |                 |                |         |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+-----------------+----------------+---------+
| 13/9/2017 | 9:30AM  | $22.45  | Card | Delivery | deliver to rear | ReturnCustomer | yes     |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+-----------------+----------------+---------+
| 13/9/2017 | 9:45AM  | $-34.00 | Cash | Refund   |                 |                |         |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+-----------------+----------------+---------+
| 13/9/2017 | 10:00AM | $17.67  | Card | Deposit  | 10%             |                |         |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+----------+-----------------+----------------+---------+
```

In theory there could be no limit to the number of comments attached to each transaction but in reality it is never more than 5.

Comment: seach for Dynamic PIVOT

Comment: I did but I couldn't figure out how to pivot 2 columns multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is another way (for multiple column pivoting)

```
; with CTE as
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Date, Time, Amount, Type
                                          order by Date)
    from   yourtable
)
SELECT Date, Time, Amount, Type,
       Comment1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN comment END),
       Detail1  = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN detail END),
       Comment2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN comment END),
       Detail2  = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN detail END),
       . . . .
FROM   cte
GROUP BY Date, Time, Amount, Type
```

it can be easily convert to dynamic query if you have unknown no of data set